# Hibernate Projection set column to 1

Tags: hibernate

Given this Detached query:

```
DetachedCriteria notExistInCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ReportTelephonyEvent.class, "r2");
notExistInCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("child", child));
notExistInCriteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("countryCode", "r1.countryCode"));
notExistInCriteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("phonenumber", "r1.phonenumber"));
notExistInCriteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.lt("startTime", start), Restrictions.gt("startTime", end)));
notExistInCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("phonenumber"));
```

I have now set Projection "phonenumber", but I want to set it 1, such that the out put query will be something like this':

```
SELECT 1 FROM bpr_report_telephony_event .............
```

How can I set Projection such that Hibernate just have "1" in the select columns?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing Projections.property("phonenumber") with Projections.sqlProjection("1") should do it.

Comment: There is no such method. What you are referring to is `Projections.sqlProjection(String sql, String[] columnAliases, Type[] types)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get "1" as the result of the projection, you can do:

```
notExistInCriteria.setProjection(Projections.sqlProjection("1", new String[]{}, new Type[] { IntegerType.INSTANCE })
```